# When should I give my boss notice for having accepted an offer of a new job?

Tags: contracts, quitting, notice-period

I've been working at my current company for the 6 months since graduation and have accepted an offer of a new job (more in line with my career goals, better pay, exciting products). I have the offers in writing--as emails--and a tentative start date, but am waiting on a contract.

My boss has just assigned me a large project which I should be able to complete in the time before I leave, although it might be tight. I want to give him warning that I'm planning on leaving around project wrap up, since clients and a lot of money is involved. However, I'm not sure whether I should wait until the contract is finalised for my new job before giving notice at my current one.

Should I wait or should I give notice now? I have to give a month's notice, but that deadline would be in 10 days' time. My boss has been good to me and I don't want to inconvenience him any more than I am already by leaving.

Comment: Wait for contract - employee turn over is cost of business.

Comment: Until you have a contract, you have nothing. Don't leap until you can see the landing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some comments have mentioned, don't jump ship at your current place until you've got something in writing that you've accepted, it sounds like for you this will be the 'contract' you mentioned.

I'm also surprised you have a 1 month notice period, could you add your location?

In the US, commonly it's a courtesy to provide 2 weeks' notice, but technically in many roles here since it's 'at-will' employment, employees could just leave with no notice at all if they wanted to do so and upset their employer / coworkers.

To summarize, I would recommend waiting until you have everything else worked out with the other position.

> You don't want to give notice at this job, and have something significant fall through at this other place and have to begin looking elsewhere while leaving this job already.

Comment: I'm in New Zealand, but yes, it is an unusually long notice period (and is in my contract)